# webgrid default sort direction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, webgrid, sortdirection

when i add the web grid to my page in mvc project it sortes the data ascending on first click.
but i bring the data already sorted ascendin. then nothing happens. i want webgrid to sort descending at first.

you can see the code of my grid creation

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, 
selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
```

by the way i have tried the below code but it doesnt work.

```
if (Request.QueryString[grid.SortDirectionFieldName].IsEmpty())
{
    grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `defaultSort` property to your `WebGrid` instantiator:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",
           ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent", defaultSort: "YourColumnName");
```